# Shared Access Signatures in Azure for client blob access

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

We have files stored in azure blobs and need to secure access to them so that only our installed Windows 8 Store App can download these blobs. My first thought was to use some sort of certificate. When the app is installed, it is installed with a certificate that it then passes in the header of the request to he server to obtain the blob.

I read about Shared Access Signatures and it kind of makes sense to me. It seems like an API that the client could use to obtain a temporary token granting access to the blobs. Great. How do I restrict access to the API for obtaining SAS tokens to only our installed client apps?

Thank you.

Comment: Not knowing completely about your application/architecture, I'm guessing you would need some kind of token using which you can identify that the request to generate Shared Access Signature is coming from your application only. Can you describe your application architecture in somewhat more details?

Answer (score 1):

Using SAS urls is the proper way to do this, this way you can give up a specific resource for a limited amount of time (15 minutes for example) and with limited permissions (only read for example).

Since this app is installed on the users machine you can assume the user can see whatever the App is doing so there is no absolute way to secure your API to only be accessed by only your App, but you can make it a little more difficult to replicate by using SSL (https) endpoint and providing some "secret key" only your App knows.